# Javascript modal window code reconfigured to load on page load rather than onclick. Help :)

Tags: javascript, window, modal-dialog, pageload

I have a js modal window which opens with an onclick function in a page on my site:

```
<a class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { slideshowGroup: 'groupC0', wrapperClassName: 'wide-border', outlineType : 'rounded-white', dimmingOpacity: 0.8, align : 'center', transitions : ['expand', 'crossfade'], fadeInOut: true });" href="/images/phocagallery/thumbs/phoca_thumb_l_jen raymond_067 copy.jpg" title="jen raymond_067 copy">
<img alt="jen raymond_067 copy" src="/images/phocagallery/thumbs/phoca_thumb_m_jen raymond_067 copy.jpg">
</a>
```

I need this triggered as the page loads (not onclick, as above). I've been playing around with this js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
window.location.href = "/images/phocagallery/thumbs/phoca_thumb_l_jen raymond_067 copy.jpg";
});
</script>
```

But of course it only loads the image (href) - can you help include the class, title and onclick attributes to this js function - or is there a better way?

Please show me the light :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the solutions above, maybe I'm just not knowledgable with JS, but I couldn't see my way using either, however I did get what I wanted using this method:

1) Add an ID to the Anchor tag

```
<a id="autoClick" class="highslide" onClick="return hs.expand(this, { slideshowGroup: 'groupC0', wrapperClassName: 'wide-border', outlineType : 'rounded-white', dimmingOpacity: 0.8, align : 'center', transitions : ['expand', 'crossfade'], fadeInOut: true });" href="/images/phocagallery/thumbs/phoca_thumb_l_jen raymond_067 copy.jpg" title="jen raymond_067 copy">
    <img alt="jen raymond_067 copy" src="/images/phocagallery/thumbs/phoca_thumb_m_jen raymond_067 copy.jpg">
</a>
```

2) Load JQuery if not already present

3) Add this function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#autoClick').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (keeping in mind I have no idea what this function does):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    hs.expand($('.highslide'), { 
         slideshowGroup: 'groupC0', 
         wrapperClassName: 'wide-border', 
         outlineType : 'rounded-white', 
         dimmingOpacity: 0.8, 
         align : 'center', 
         transitions : ['expand', 'crossfade'], fadeInOut: true });
    });
```

Thats the best I can come up with without looking up the hs(highlide?) api.

Comment: fantastic, Q for you, how does this integrate with the 'window.location.href' ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if i add it into the function, or use as its own function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var yourAElement = $('.highslide')[0];
    hs.expand(yourAElement, { slideshowGroup: 'groupC0', wrapperClassName: 'wide-border', outlineType : 'rounded-white', dimmingOpacity: 0.8, align : 'center', transitions : ['expand', 'crossfade'], fadeInOut: true });
});
```

Comment: thank you, not sure how to implement this with 'window.location.href ...' Doesn't seem to work if i add it into the function, or use as its own function.

Comment: window.location.href will NAVIGATE to a whole new page so then you will be losing the current page you are on. So unless that's what you want to do, you have to use your method in the onclick

Comment: Of course, silly of me. So what i need is an onload function or something?, instead of the onclick (so the modal window with image in it loads automatically) - window.location.href was never going to work for a modal window. Doah

Comment: the $(function() {}); is the same thing as $(document).ready(function(){});  so basically it will be using the onload only once everything is ready.